# how to show two seperate random items from 2 listbox into a messagebox?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, button, random

I have 2 listbox, one for 'names' and one for 'what they did' I have a textbox assigned to each of these listbox and an add button for each so the user can enter whatever 'name' or 'what they did' they want into the 2 listbox. I have a create button which will show the result of this in a message box and thats easy, but I want it to show a random combination each time.

So in the 'name' listbox I could have entered the names Jerry, Dean, Mary and in the 'what they did' I could have entered Sat, Slept, Cried. On the press of the create button I want a random item from both lists so the result could be 'Dean Cried' then the next time I press create it could be 'Jerry Slept'

I have been able to, with some help get a random item on each press of the create button from the name box but I am having trouble getting my code to make it happen for both.

```
    private void btnaddname_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stringname = textBoxname.Text;
        textBoxname.Clear();
        listboxname.Items.Add(stringname);    
    }


    private void btnaddwhat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stringwhat = textBoxwhat.Text;
        textBoxwhat.Clear();
        listBoxwhat.Items.Add(stringwhat);
    }


    private void buttoncreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(1, listboxname.Items.Count);
        listboxname.Select();
        listboxname.SelectedItem = listboxname.Items[randomNumber];


        Random randomwhat = new Random();
        int randomnumwhat = randomwhat.Next(1, listBoxwhat.Items.Count);
        listBoxwhat.Select();
        listBoxwhat.SelectedItem = listBoxwhat.Items[randomnumwhat];

        MessageBox.Show(listboxname.SelectedItem.ToString() + (" ") + (listBoxwhat.SelectedItem.ToString()));

    }
```

Comment: I can't see anything glaringly obvious. Can you elaborate on "I am having trouble getting my code to make it happen for both"? What error are you getting? Have you tried debugging? Are the relevant event handlers definitely being fired? Also (as an aside), I think you could greatly benefit from putting this code up for review on the relevant SE site as there are a few issues they could help you with (naming conventions, unnecessary parentheses etc.).

Comment: I am not getting any actual errors, but once I try to enter code to make the secon listbox random when I press 'Create' it will just show the selected items and not make them random, it will come up with the same result each time. If I don't put code to make the second listbox random then the result makes the item from the first listbox random and the second just the selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create just one Random variable and use it for both list...

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(1, listboxname.Items.Count);
listboxname.Select();
listboxname.SelectedItem = listboxname.Items[randomNumber];


int randomnumwhat = random.Next(1, listBoxwhat.Items.Count);
listBoxwhat.Select();
listBoxwhat.SelectedItem = listBoxwhat.Items[randomnumwhat];

MessageBox.Show(listboxname.SelectedItem.ToString() + (" ") +(listBoxwhat.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

Comment: Exactly, if you create new instances of the Random class close enough in time, they will generate the same sequence as they are both seeded by the system clock (unless otherwise specified in the constructor)

Always create one instance and reuse it as much as possible.

Comment: Works, thank you! I can see where I was going wrong now and wont make that mistake again